# Aiogram проблемы с отправкой сообщения

Tags: python, aiogram, sendmessage

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.dispatcher.storage import FSMContext
from PrimeBot import dp, bot, api, storage

async def dilog(dp: Dispatcher, message: types.Message):
    await send_question(message)
   ###Состояния из ммашины состояний###
    await dp.register_message_handler(calc_gender)
    await dp.register_message_handler(calc_weight)
    await dp.register_message_handler(calc_height)
    await dp.register_message_handler(calc_lifestyl)

async def send_question(message: types.Message):

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши свой пол (м/ж): ')
```

Этот метод срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку из другого файла, нажимаю ничего не происходит. Выходит ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: На какую строку *вашего* кода указывает ошибка?

Comment: Также приведите полную ошибку

Answer (score 0):

```
 async def dilog(dp: Dispatcher, callback: types.CallbackQuery):

     await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Напиши свой пол (м/ж): ")
     return await Calculator.Gender.set()
```

Вот такое решение, оказалось машина состояний вызывается именно так, декораторы нужно оставить. Насчет вывода сообщений я вызывал этот код из другого файла, во время обработки callback, так что тут тоже нужно использовать его.